# C++ : Convert Decimal to RGB Values

Tags: c++, rgb

Is there an efficient way to calculate the RGB (255,255,255) values from a decimal in C++?

I have seen it be done on a website, but I wanted to know if its possible in C++ as it will be quicker.

The website that does it is this one, you may have a good idea at what I'm trying to ask.

https://www.checkyourmath.com/convert/color/decimal_rgb.php

Comment: HINT: `RGB(255,255,255)` == `RGB(0xff,0xff,0xff)`.  So just 1) convert the three numbers from decimal to hex, 2) glom the three hex digit pairs together, 3) the result is your 32-bit unsigned int number :)  Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/RGB) for more details on what "RGB" means (in terms of HTML/CSS).

Comment: `unsigned b = rgb & 0xff; unsigned g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff; unsigned r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the decimal value is composed as `..RRGGBB`
Something like this:

```
unsigned int color = <some value>
unsigned int red = (color & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
unsigned int green = (color & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
unsigned int blue = (color & 0x000000FF);
```

You might need to swap the assignments depending on how the values were packed to begin with. Some platforms may invert these colors.